# Хочу сделать сумму n-чисел c n-строк(с переводом с string в int с помощью stringstream),но в переменную d постоянно записывается только первое число

Tags: c++, stringstream

```
{
int n, i, q=0, d = 0,f=0;
string s;
stringstream ss;
inf >> n;
getline(inf, s);
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    getline(inf, s);
    ss << s;
    ss >> d;
    q = q + d;
}
outf << q << endl;
```

}
//пример input
(каждое число с новой строки)
5//число n строк
11
12
13
14
15
output: 55(5 раз добавило 11)

Comment: А почему бы при этом еще и в файл не писать в количестве 5 штук?... Или еще чего посложнее придумать? `stoi` уже под запретом?

Comment: с stoi сделать не проблема,только вот у меня условие именно с stringstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, раз уж так надо - то сначала все запишите, а потом читайте... Примерно так:

```
ifstream inf("data");
stringstream ss;
int n, q = 0;
string s;
inf >> n;
getline(inf, s);
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    getline(inf, s);
    ss << s << " "; // Лучше добавить пробел, чтоб числа не сливались
}
for(int d, i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    ss >> d;
    q = q + d;
}
cout << q << endl;
```

Ну, или так:

```
ifstream inf("data");
int n, q = 0;
string s;
inf >> n;
getline(inf, s);
for(int d, i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    stringstream ss;
    getline(inf, s);
    ss << s << " ";
    ss >> d;
    q = q + d;
}
cout << q << endl;
```

Comment: Спасибо!(cout<<d<<endl; лишнее)

Comment: А, да, это я смотрел, как работает... Ну, если ответ устроил - то принимайте, птичка слева от ответа.

Comment: Что за ерунда? Уж ответ принять имеете право только вы.